# updating @State variable in swiftUI not cause to reload when using delegate which called from outside

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-state, swift-property-wrapper

I have this code:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyWatchApp: App {
    
    @State var myEnum: MyEnum = .first

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            getCorrectView()
        }
    }

    func getCorrectView() -> some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
            self.update(.second) // this works
        }

        switch myEnum {
            case .first: return AnyView(Text("First"))
            case .second: return AnyView(Text("Second"))
        }
    }
}
extension MyWatchApp: MyDelegate {
    func update(_ newState: MyEnum) {
        // when this func calls from outside, this print called but view not reloads
        // when this func calls from my getCorrectView, works as expected
        print("state updated")
        myEnum = newState
    }
}
```

My problem is that calling "update" function from other class, calles method, even print() called but view not reloads like when this function called from inside this file.

Comment: You have to use the variable in the body also any view los discouraged watch Demystify SwiftUI

Comment: if I define the variable in the body, it's not accessible from other functions.

Comment: I didn't say define, I sad use. Also, Views are synchronous that DispatchQueue would mess with how views build.